# Sum only values 1 from array

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I have array with variables from $qA01_1 up to $qA30_5 (150 variables). Some of the variables can have value 0 or 1 or 5 (example $qA21_3 = 0 or 1 or 5). And I would like to know how to make sum of all variables which have value 1.

Here part of array

```
$qA01_1 = $_SESSION['qA01_1']; // example: $qA01_01 can have value 0 or 1 or 5, like other variables  
$qA01_2 = $_SESSION['qA01_2']; // $qA01_02 = 0 or 1 or 5
$qA01_3 = $_SESSION['qA01_3']; // $qA01_03 = 0 or 1 or 5
$qA01_4 = $_SESSION['qA01_4']; // $qA01_04 = 0 or 1 or 5
$qA01_5 = $_SESSION['qA01_5']; // $qA01_05 = 0 or 1 or 5

$qA02_1 = $_SESSION['qA02_1']; // $qA02_01 = 0 or 1 or 5   
$qA02_2 = $_SESSION['qA02_2']; // $qA02_02 = 0 or 1 or 5
$qA02_3 = $_SESSION['qA02_3']; // $qA02_03 = 0 or 1 or 5
$qA02_4 = $_SESSION['qA02_4']; // $qA02_04 = 0 or 1 or 5
$qA02_5 = $_SESSION['qA02_5']; // $qA02_05 = 0 or 1 or 5

// up to...

$qA30_1 = $_SESSION['qA30_1']; // $qA30_01 = 0 or 1 or 5    
$qA30_2 = $_SESSION['qA30_2']; // $qA30_02 = 0 or 1 or 5
$qA30_3 = $_SESSION['qA30_3']; // $qA30_03 = 0 or 1 or 5
$qA30_4 = $_SESSION['qA30_4']; // $qA30_04 = 0 or 1 or 5
$qA30_5 = $_SESSION['qA30_5']; // $qA30_05 = 0 or 1 or 5
```

Here is proposal but not work. I´m begginer, please for help.

```
$values = [];
for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++)
{
    foreach([1,2,3,4,5] as $index) 
    {
        if(${'qA'.str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'_'.$index} == 1) 
        {
            $values[] = ${'qA'.str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'_'.$index};
        }
    }
} 
echo $values;
```

Comment: Can you share a truncated representation of the array. I can't picture what you're trying to do.

Comment: @dan08 Part of array added.

Comment: Why are you using separate variables instead of iterating over the array?

Comment: Any time you find yourself using variable variables, you're probably doing something unnecessary.

Comment: What is index value of these arrays like  $qA01_1[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a sum, you don't need the `$values` array. Just add the value to a `$sum` variable.

```
$sum = 0;
for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++)
{
    foreach([1,2,3,4,5] as $index) 
    {
        $var = 'qA'.str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'_'.$index
        if(${$var} == 1) 
        {
            $sum += ${$var};
        }
    }
} 
echo $sum;
```

BTW, you can't echo an array. If you want to see the contents of an array, use `var_dump($values);` or `print_r($values);`

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the `$_SESSION` array:

```
// This is where we'll hold all the saved numbers
// from values ending with _1
$array_of_numbers = [];

// Loop through each session
foreach ( $_SESSION as $key => $val )
{
  // Only save the keys that match and equal 1
  if ( preg_match('/^qA\d{2}?_\d$/', $key, $matches) && $val == 1 )
  {
    $array_of_numbers[] = $val;
  }
}

// Sum the numbers that we gathered
$sum_of_array = array_sum($array_of_numbers);
```

Comment: You are trying to sum variables contain number one in name. But I need to do sum variables which has values 1.

Comment: I don't think anyone understood that from your question. In that case, replace the regex match with a condition to check the value. I'll update my answer to reflect this soon.

Comment: I´ve add more info in original question. I hope that my question is clearer than before.

Comment: Made a quick edit from my phone. You do not technically need to use `array_sum` since the values you want always equal 1, you could just increase an iterator. I kept my solution how it is, though, so you can have the flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Time for a rethink. No reason to unpack the array like you are doing.

Lets put the `$_SESSION` values that we are interested in into a new array and work with that. (not necessary to put in to a new array, I just prefer to not work with the super global variables more than necessary)

```
//Create new array
$myArray = [];
foreach( $_SESSION as $key=>$val ){
  if( preg_match('/qA\d{2}_[1-5]/', $key) ){
    $myArray[$key] = $val;
  }
}

$sum = 0;
foreach( $myArray as $key=>$val ){
  if( preg_match('/qA\d{2}_1/', $key) ){
    $sum += $val;
  }
}

var_dump($sum);
```

Comment: I thing that my question was a little bit confusing. I`ve add more info in general question. You are trying to sum variables contain number one in name. But I need to do sum variables which has values 1.

Answer (score 0):

Since the logic here is a bit confusing, I think separating it out into a couple "self-documenting" functions would be better practice. Something like this should work:

```
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++) {
        $qa_index = qa_index($i, $j);
        if ($_SESSION[$qa_index] == 1)
            $sum++; // no need to _actually_ sum since it's just 1
    }
}

function qa_index($major, $minor) {
    return 'qA'.left_pad_zeros($major).'_'.$minor."\n";
}

function left_pad_zeros($val, $pad_amount = 2) {
    return str_pad($val, $pad_amount, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

EDIT: I imagine some people might think functions are unnecessary overhead here. And that may be IF whatever application is using this NEEDS to squeeze out every little bit of performance improvement they can. However, if that's not the case, I think this is much better practice as it is much easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $TotalVal = 0;
 for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    for($j=1; $j<=5; $j++){
      If($i<10){
    $StrVar = 'qA0'.$j.'_'.$i.'[0]'; // considering ur using array if not remove [0].
      If ($$StrVar == 1)
        $TotalVal = $TotalVal + $$StrVar;
      }else{
       $StrVar = 'qA'.$j.'_'.$i.'[0]';
       If ($$StrVar == 1)
         $TotalVal = $TotalVal + $$StrVar;
      }
   }
}
echo $TotalVal;
```

This will give you sum of all values which is having 1 if u need 5 change in if condition